# Store Camera Roll photos into array to display with Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

I wish to get all the photos from the Camera Roll and display them full screen like a screen saver. The photo will change to the next photo in the Camera Roll after every 5 seconds. I want to store these photos or photo names in an array so I can loop through the array and display them which i am having difficulty.

```
import Photos

@IBOutlet weak var ssImage: UIImageView!
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
var arrayPhoto: [UIImage] = []

func FetchPhotos() {
    let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

    //Get the file names of all the photos and store into arrayPhoto
}

//Gets index of current image from array and increment 1 so as to display the next photo every 5 seconds.
func nextImage() {
    let currentIndex = arrayPhoto.index(of: imageView.image ?? UIImage()) ?? -1
    var nextIndex = currentIndex+1 
    nextIndex = arrayPhoto.indices.contains(nextIndex) ? nextIndex : 0
    UIView.transition(with: ssImage, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: { self.ssImage.image = self.arrayPhoto[nextIndex] }, completion: nil)
    ssImage.image = arrayPhoto[nextIndex]
}

func scheduledTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: (#selector(nextImage)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad
    FetchPhotos()
    scheduledTimer()
}
```

Comment: best option is get all phasset from camera roll after then give it one by one orignal image to your imageview

Answer (score 0):

The assets which you are getting it from `fetchAssets` will not guarantee the image or video data because it might not be stored on the local device and it can be in iCloud. So before use your `PHAsset`, need to make sure that we have the underlying image is downloaded or in the device. Photos API is giving lots of API for our needs on accessing and using photos, videos, burst shots and live photos.

For your specific need, you might need to check [PHCachingImageManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phcachingimagemanager). It gives us the ability to download or prepare asset images in the background. As per the documentation below are the steps

> 1. Create a PHCachingImageManager instance. (This step replaces using the shared PHImageManager instance.)
> 2. Use PHAsset class methods to fetch the assets you’re interested in.
> 3. To prepare images for those assets, call the  startCachingImages(for:targetSize:contentMode:options:)  method with
>      the target size, content mode, and options you plan to use when later
>      requesting images for each individual asset.
> 4. When you need an image for an individual asset, call the  requestImage(for:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:)
>      method, and pass the same parameters you used when preparing that
>      asset.
>
> If the image you request is among those already prepared, the
>   PHCachingImageManager object immediately returns that image.
>   Otherwise, Photos prepares the image on demand and caches it for later
>   use.

Comment: Hi, can you give a skeleton of the code? I am totally lost as I am new to Swift /ObjC.